# How can I make my application using Spotify API accessible to other users?

Tags: python, api, spotify, spotipy

I currently have a python script implemented using the Spotipy python library based on the Spotify API. However, I would like to make it accessible to more users who wouldn't have their own CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET etc. How could I do this? I'm currently using Authorization Code Flow and when a different user logs in, it raises an exception and says 'You cannot create a playlist for another user." Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and you should (re-)read the help topic [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to get a feeling on how to contribute. You should at least provide a minimal, complete and reproducible example ([MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) of your code.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to make it an API and host it as part of a python web server. Here is a full working example that would allow multiple users to sign in https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/blob/master/examples/app.py.

It uses Flask but you could adapt it to Django, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to provide correct scope parameter during authorization flow (below is the basic example in node.js). Scope basically defines what all permissions you have requested from the end user.

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
var scopes = 'user-read-private user-read-email';
res.redirect('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize' +
  '?response_type=code' +
  '&client_id=' + my_client_id +
  (scopes ? '&scope=' + encodeURIComponent(scopes) : '') +
  '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(redirect_uri));
});
```

Snippet referenced from [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/).

Also, check the list of scopes and their description [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/scopes/). If you do not find appropriate scope for your purpose, unfortunately, it's a blocker for you.

Comment: I already have scopes 'playlist-modify-public user-read-recently-played'. My application simply creates a playlist of the user's recently played tracks so I don't see what else I would need

Comment: If the API is throwing "You cannot create a playlist for another user." error, you are probably creating a playlist which is private to the user. In my opinion you should try adding 'playlist-modify-private' to the list of scopes.